# How to Change the splash color when tapping DropdownButton In flutter?

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

In `DropdownButton` widget of the flutter, I want to change the splash color when tapping. Although I change the `focusColor` of the `DropdownButton` but nothing changes... How to do this???

```
Container(
              height: 20,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 10,
                left: 10,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(38),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Color(0xFFEAD6EE),
                  )),
              child: DropdownButton(
                focusColor: Color(0xFFC88FFF),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: fontColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text('$editedCountry'),
                items: dropdownMenuItemByCategory('Country'),
                onChanged: (editedIndValue) {
                  _onCountrySelected(editedIndValue);
                },
                value: editedCountryID,
                underline: SizedBox(),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `DropdownButton` with `Theme`

```dart
Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      splashColor: Colors.red, //change based your need
    ),
    child: DropdownButton(
```